# 4D Web Server and session variables

Tags: http, cookies, session-variables, 4d-database

I'm working on a Website made with the proprietary DBMS "[4th Dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_dimension)". I'm really *struggling* with this, as I'm still a beginner, and I only have experience with PHP on client-server apps. 4D provides a Web Server that can handle GET and POST requests, and send basic responses to the client.

**My question is:**
There seems to be no equivalent of PHP's `$_SESSION` to store persistant variables, but I have to keep a browsing history during the visitor's session, what's the good way to achieve that?

I don't even have a clue on how I could identify a single visitor during his visit.
I would really appreciate some help.
Regards,
caffein

**TL;DR** What's the best way to mimic PHP's session in any language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this Summit session from the 4D knowledge base: [Web Session Management: Tracking Your Web Users](http://kb.4d.com/search/assetid=75741). It is complete with notes and a sample .4DB.

I'd also recommend a more thorough search on the [KB and the iNUG](http://kb.4d.com) mailing list (you have to be [manually approved](http://lists.4d.com/) before you can post, but you can browse archives).

As much as I like SO the iNUG really is the best place to get in touch with 4D devs.

Comment: Thank you for your accurate answer. 4D hasn't a very open community, and it's hard to find answers; this question was kind of a bottle in the sea. By the way, I find unthinkable for a modern language not to propose a native way to manage sessions.

Answer (score 0):

The 4d v14 has native session management; to active it it is enough to set on the "Automatic Session Management" option in Database Settings ( cfr [4d Web Session Management](http://doc.4d.com/4D-Language-Reference-14/Web-Server/Web-Sessions-Management.300-1180012.en.html) ) or use the command WEB SET OPTION(Web Keep session; true).

The session is maintained from 4d using cookies; every process variable and records selection is maintained.

In the code of "On Web Connection" Database method you can write:

```
C_TEXT(www_SessionID)
If(www_SessionID=**WEB Get Current Session ID**)
    // All variables and selection already exist
    ...
Else
    // Compiler_Web has just been executed.
    // This is a new session, no variable or selection exists
    // Keep track of the session that 4D just created
    www_SessionID:=**WEB Get Current Session ID**

    // Initialization of session
    // Set up selections
    // find connected user
    QUERY([User];[User]Login=www_Login)
    QUERY([prefs];[prefs]Login=www_Login)

    // Setup variables
    // Get prefs for this user
    www_UserName:=[User]Name
    www_UserMail:=[User]mail
End if
```